# Calling assembly : (Unknown) , when trying to connect OracleDB with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, .net-assembly

I am trying to connect Oracle DB without installing oracle client but it could't not establish connection.I have dowloaded xcopy files from Oracle site and place the Oracle.DataAccess.dll in GAC with command :

```
gacutil /i “<Application Path>\ Oracle.DataAccess.dll”
```

and also some tags added to my Web.config file such as :

```
<system.data>

<DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Unmanaged Driver" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory,Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

```
 <provider invariantName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory,  Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />

 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89B483F429C47342" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.102.0.0-4.120.0.0" newVersion="4.121.2.0" />
</assemblyBinding>
```

But none of attemp , application can not open the connection to oracle and browser give the error

[image]

Stack Trace :

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +21
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38



[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +92
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531



[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9920760
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

How can I solve this problem? I can connect to OracleDB via visual studio data connection but I can not do that programatically. I am always taking these error when the interpreter comes to the line "conn.open()". I am on this problem about 2 days but I couldn't solve yet. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Maybe you should install the Oracle Client - apparently there are more assemblies needed than just Oracle.DataAccess.dll. Best of luck.

Comment: I have already added the neded library like OraOps11w.dll,oramts.dll,oramts11.dll,oci.dll, orannzsbb11.dll, oraociei11.dll .

Comment: Why not use the instant client? This client does not require running an installer.

Comment: Try Managed ODP.net -- it does not require a client at all.  It doesn't have *all* of the features of ODP.net (bulk updates were missing last time I checked), but for day to day queries, inserts, updates, etc it's pretty darn good and removes that pesky dependency on the client.

Comment: `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` needs a Oracle Client installation. Trying to make in manually will end in a mess.